# TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.db.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do you get the data from the document using document id? I am trying to get the current signed in user details from the document using the id, but i am not able to retrive the details.

```
import{useState} from 'react';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from '../../firebase';

const Single = () => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
  const auth = getAuth();


onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const uid = user.uid;
      setUserId(uid)
    } else {

    }
  });

const docData = db.collection("users").doc(userId).get();
setUserData(docData)

console.log(docData)
}
```

Comment: See the linked questions and please search for any error message you get going forward. In your case, the syntax would be something like `await getDoc(doc(db, "users", userId));`

Comment: that gave me an infinite loop. I'm not trying to loop through the whole collection. I only need data from that specific document which is the the user that has been logged in.

Comment: i get this: errors.ts:94 Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1.

Comment: It sounds like `userId` doesn't have a value then. You might want to check that with an `if` in your code.

Comment: when i do console.log(userId), it prints the id of uset that has been logged in

Comment: I recommend posting a new question (as this question was about the v8 syntax you used) with the code you code have, including the check for `null` on the UID that I mentioned.